# I want to smooth only the outer faces of a circle

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface

I am currently working on a medal where I want a smooth the extreme outer part of it but without touching the rest especially the upper face.  However even when I add one subdivision modifier, I get the result I want but the upper face grove lines emitting from the central circle are ruined.  A you can see in the photos.

I  have marked the edges as sharp (Edit mode/mesh/shading/sharp) but without a result.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: How important is clean topology (quads only) to you, because I can think of a hack to achieve that.

Comment: I am working to 3d print it.

Comment: Hi. Please try to use existing tags instead of creating new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, for 3d Print this should work fine:
[image]

1. Add 2 edge loops along the sides.
2. Press CRTL num plus to extend your selection, so it covers the entire rim
3. W -> subdivide
4. Choose these options (lower left at your VP imediately after hitting subdivide)
   [image]

You might need to tweak the rim, bc. it may become concave. Easiest would probably to delete the new edge loops around the "coin" again.

Comment: THANKS for the help. After 2 hours of tweakings, I used your suggestion but subdivided it a lot more and above you can see the result.  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to separate into 2 different objects and apply the subdivision just to the outer object?

Comment: might be a good one but I would need to reunite them in the end since I am working to 3d print it.

Comment: Adding smoothness to parts of your mesh and joining it back together is bound to create holes.

Comment: OK I did'nt realise that you needed to print it. Joining will be no good.